# Preload item in recycler view(recycler inside recycler)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, prefetch

I have a vertical recyclerview with multiples types like horizontal recycler inside.

My problem concern an item not visible (so not bind yet) at the start of the fragment (i.e maybe the item number 6 ou 7 of the list).

This item is an horizontal recycler view and when I first scroll to the bottom I have a lag when the item is binding...

I already optimzed my xml to have just 1 parent view
I already set fixed size to true
I already also setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)

So, I tried to use pretech item count from this article (
https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710) but I don't see the difference. (maybe I don't implement it correctly)

I am asking if I can really bind this item (it's an horizontal recycler) when he is not visible...

I want to keep the main recycler and don't inflate manually a linear layout because I have a lot of view types ( I tried but the solution was pretty ugly).

Thanks in avance